# SQLSTATE[08006] [7] could not translate host name "dbname=" to address

Tags: sql, postgresql, symfony, authentication, silex

I'm using the Symfony/Silex SecurityServiceProvider to login users on the site.

```
http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/providers/security.html
```

I follow the guide step by step, but when I submit the login form, I got a PostgreSQL error

```
SQLSTATE[08006] [7] could not translate host name "dbname=" to address
```

Whatever I set for dbname, I still got the error. Even with the right IP of the distant server. However my setup is good, because I use the same class to connect and request the server, and it always work.

The error appears only on submitting the login form !

My login class

```
<?php

namespace Model;

use Silex\Application;

abstract class Entity {

    private $app;
    private $host;
    private $base;
    private $port;
    private $user;
    private $pass;
    private $charset;

    public function __construct(Application $app)
    {
        $this->app = $app;

        $this->host    = $app['config']['database']['host'];
        $this->base    = $app['config']['database']['base'];
        $this->port    = $app['config']['database']['port'];
        $this->user    = $app['config']['database']['user'];
        $this->pass    = $app['config']['database']['pass'];
        $this->charset = $app['config']['database']['charset'];
    }

    protected function connectBDD()
    {
        $connect = new \PDO("pgsql:host=$this->host;dbname=$this->base", $this->user, $this->pass);
        $connect->setAttribute(\PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $connect->query("SET NAMES '$this->charset'");

        return $connect;
    }
}
}
```

Thanks for help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You config values are empty. `$app['config']['database']['host']` is empty and connection looks like `$connect = new \PDO("pgsql:host=;dbname=", ...);`
Try to dump config to see values

```
public function __construct(Application $app)
{
    dump($app['config']['database']);
    ...
}
```